# Configuring Nancy to manage Client Certificates

Tags: c#, authentication, ssl, nancy

I'm facing problem configuring Nancy server to manage client certificates. The fact is that web browser asks for a client certification but the page is served by Nancy even if I press cancel and I don't choose any certificate.

My code:

```
var hostConf = new HostConfiguration()
{
    EnableClientCertificates = true,
    UnhandledExceptionCallback = e =>
    {
        var message = String.Format("---\n{0}\n---\n", e);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    },
    UrlReservations = new UrlReservations() { CreateAutomatically = true}
};

host = new NancyHost(hostConf, new Uri(httpsServiceHost));
```

Also, I don't know the relationship between the `EnableClientCertificates` field and the `clientcertnegotiation=enabled` from `netsh http add sslcert ... clientcertnegotiation=enabled`

Please could somebody help me?